# Is graphology and handwriting analysis permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

I want to ask, is graphology or handwriting analysis is permitted in Islam?
Here's the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphology):

> Graphology is the pseudoscientific study and analysis of handwriting,
>   especially in relation to human psychology. In the medical field, the
>   word can be used to refer to the study of handwriting as an aid in
>   diagnosis and tracking of diseases of the brain and nervous system.
>   The term is sometimes incorrectly used to refer to forensic document
>   examination.
>
> Graphology has been controversial for more than a century. Although
>   supporters point to the anecdotal evidence of thousands of positive
>   testimonials as a reason to use it for personality evaluation, most
>   empirical studies fail to show the validity claimed by its supporters.

A local syekh says it's okay, but there's some limitation. I know what's the detail of limitation. Some trace can identified using logic, ex: if your handwriting size is small, you are more focus than persons who have bigger handwriting size.

Previously I already search how the inventor of graphology exactly get the result (e.g. "if your t crossbar is low, your motivation and self-esteem is low", and most important, how can graphologist come to conclusion like this? Using research / "research" / just guessing ?), but i don't know where to startand i don't get reference about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no element of the unseen in handwriting analysis or graphology - all the assertions made are from statistical analysis or handwriting study over thousands of subjects. What is prohibited is to purport to give knowledge of the unseen, but this is simply telling people what is statistically likely about their personality based on some outward manifestation. Given the purely scientific and empirical nature of this science, there is no reason why it should not be permissible.